# How to append html formatted data from node js server to html file in client side?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to build a site in plain javascript, node and handlebars that, trough a quote calculator, the user could request a list of several items to the owner of the site. 
The data formatted in json such as:

```
{ "item": "candy", "brand":"delicious candy" }
```

would be inserted by the user in index.html. 
The site then would perform some validations and then send it to the server through the fetch api attached to a event in a button somehow like 'send quote'

```
app.post('/api', (request, response) => {
let quote = request.body;
response.render('admin', quote);
```

Then HandleBars would insert the data in html such as:

```
<h1> Candy </h1>
<h2> Delicious candy </h2>
```

And here is where I'm stuck, I'm capable to visualize in the console the response of the api call, and apparently is sending back to the browser the data I want, but I cannot wrap my mind in how could I append this HTML to a HTML file called admin.html.

[image]

[image: aproximation of data flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you at all familiar with jQuery?  What you could do is create an empty paragraph tag in your Handlebars HTML.

```
<p id="candyData">

</p>
```

Then, in your JS file where you're adding your event listener for the submit button on your form, query the paragraph by ID.

```
const candyData = document.querySelector('#candyData');
```

Now, in your fetch to your server, it could look something like this to get the value to the page.

```
fetch('/url').then((response) => {
  response.json().then((data) => {
    if (data.error) {
      candyData.textContent = data.error;
    } else {
      candyData.textContent = data.candyDataObj // candyDataObj should be accessed based on how you're storing the data.
    }
  });
});
```

Don't forget to also load in the script tag in your HTML file.

```
<script src="/scripts/app.js"></script> <!-- the src path should be updated per your directory -->
```

Comment: it is showing error  "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

Comment: I don't think you're the OP for this.  Without being able to see any of your code I'm not sure what's going wrong.  I'd recommend creating a new Stackoverflow post and referencing this one.